# tymon/jwt-auth for laravel 5.4 refresh token

Tags: laravel-5

I recently using laravel 5.4 and I want to use tymon/jwt-auth package to secure my APIs by sending the access token but my issues happened when token expired I can't refresh it before expired and I expected the token will be refreshed automatically

---

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    try{
        $user = JWTAuth::parseToken()->authenticate();
    }catch (JWTException $e) {
        if($e instanceof \Tymon\JWTAuth\Exceptions\TokenExpiredException) {
            return response()->json(['token_expired'], $e->getStatusCode());
        }else if ($e instanceof \Tymon\JWTAuth\Exceptions\TokenInvalidException) {

            return response()->json(['token_invalid'], $e->getStatusCode());
        }else{
            return response()->json(['error'=>'Token is required']);
        }
    }
   return $next($request);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You only need this snippet to do authentication:

```
$credentials = request(['email', 'password']);
if (!$token = JWTAuth::attempt($credentials)) {
    return response()->json(['error' => 'Unauthorized'], 401);
}
```

Make sure you include jwt.auth & jwt.refresh on middleware at route as follow:

```
Route::Group(['middleware' => [
    'jwt.auth',
    'jwt.refresh',
]], function() {
//list your route here
....
....
....
```

jwt.refresh do refresh your token each time you access the route. And also added this in your .env

```
JWT_BLACKLIST_GRACE_PERIOD=60
```

you can adjust the number from 60 seconds to any other values. This setting will set how long the token will valid before refreshed again.